# How does a vacuum oven work?

Tags: temperature

I am doing some research on vacuum oven, but I cannot find out any website/book to tell me the theory. To my knowledge, it works better than regular oven. However, I have no idea why it is. Please help

Comment: Check this out http://www.lesker.com/newweb/menu_Systems.cfm?section=furnaces&init=skip

Comment: It explains everything you need http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QWX-Vy0YiKM
lots of stuff on youtube

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vacuum Ovens works better than regular ovens because:

- It removes the source of contamination. For example, heating metals to high temperature causes rapid oxidation in regular ovens which is undesirable.
- It reduces the heat loss which is caused by convection.
- It allows quick cooling of the product as there are no air to hold heat around product.
- It allows precise control of uniform temperature in a certain area of oven. There's no air to screw it up.

Comment: doesn't reducing :heat loss which is caused by convection" contradict "quick cooling of the product as there are no air to hold heat around product"?

Answer (score 2):

I've put together an easy to ready pdf on how vacuum works.  Check it out at:
http://www.cascadetek.com/resource/how-vacuum-works 
Hope it  helps!